# INNER JOIN Using IF logic

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I construct my left join to produce this output?

Table 1: Main Table

```
 |  ID  |  Team  |   Color    |
 |   1  |    A   |    Red     |  
 |   2  |    A   |    Blue    |  
 |   3  |    B   |    Green   |
 |   4  |    B   |    Green   |    
 |   5  |    C   |    Yellow  |
```

Table 2: Lookup Table

```
 |  Team  | Color     |  Final     |
 |    A   |  Red      |  A-1       |  
 |    A   |  Blue     |  A         |  
 |    B   |  Green    |  B         |  
 |    C   |  Yellow   |  C         |
```

Output Table

```
 |  ID  |  Team  |   Color    |  Final  |
 |   1  |    A   |    Red     |  A-1    |
 |   2  |    A   |    Blue    |  A      |
 |   3  |    B   |    Green   |  B      |
 |   4  |    B   |    Green   |  B      |  
 |   5  |    C   |    Yellow  |  C      |
```

In excel the logic would be something like this  ...

```
=IF(AND(Team = "A", Color = "Red"),"A-1", Team = Team))
```

How does this translate to an sql query in access or mysql using inner join? I have something like this but doesn't know how to construct an if statement within the query.

I want the query to check if **Team** = 'A' **AND** **Color** = 'Red' then return 'A-1' otherwise return the same Team column value.

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Team, Table1.Color, Table2.Final FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Team = Table2.Team;
```

Any help woul dbe highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a left join, it's an inner join. You should rename your question probably.

Comment: I'll do that and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your question is confusing (as you can see from the answers you got). It seems you simply want to join the tables (which are related by Team and Color, so you must of course use both in your ON clause). But then you say "... otherwise return the same Team column value". What is this supposed to mean? Is it possible not to find a match in table 2 and you need some fallback algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AND keyword in your JOIN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1  
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.Team = Table2.Team AND Table1.Color = Table2.Color
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.Team, Table1.Color, 
case Table1.Team when "A" then
case Table1.Color when "READ" then
Table2.Final 
else 
Table1.Team
end
else
Table1.Team 
end
Table2.Final FROM Table1 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Team = Table2.Team;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.ID, A.Team, B.Color, B.Final
FROM MainTable as A
LEFT JOIN LookupTable as B
    ON A.team = B.team
    AND B.Final = CASE COLOR WHEN "RED" THEN "A-1" ELSE B.Final END
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and got your expected output.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.team,
    t1.color,
    t2.final
FROM
    table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t1.Team = t2.Team AND t1.Color = t2.Color
```